# LostFocus Event and GetFocus Event for input button

Tags: asp.net, events, input, client-side

how we can set LostFocus Event and GetFocus  Event  for input button?

Answer (score 0):

in Html code in page, some method is available for input texetbox.
onfocus() and onmouseover() is like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *jQuery* to bind blur and focus events to the input button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#inputButtonId').blur(function(){
        alert('Lost Focus');
    });

    $('#inputButtonId').focus(function(){
        alert('Got Focus');
    });

});
```